# Calcu: How to add the operator before each number like a real calc

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm just trying to build a calculator and I have no idea how to prompt an operator before each number. I'm trying to build a calculator and have as many number inputs as specified but they can cancel out of it by pressing -1 and it will still return the final value.

But i tried using a string statements but I'm new to coding and don't know where to start.

```
    int operator;
    int howmany;
    int i=0;
    int all = 0;
    double div;

    int scan;
    System.out.println("Press 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for \n 
multiplication 4 for division or 5 for modules");
    operator=scanner.nextInt();
    if(operator < 1 || operator >5) {System.out.println("Restart 
calculator");System.exit(0);}
    System.out.println("How many numbers will you be using?");
    howmany = scanner.nextInt() -1 ;


    if (operator == 1){

        System.out.println("Press -1 to cancel ");

    while(i <=howmany) {

        i++;
        System.out.println("Enter number" + i);
        System.out.println("So far your numbers is " + all);
        scan = scanner.nextInt();   
        all += scan;

        if(i-1 == howmany ) {
            System.out.println("Your final answer is " + all);
        }

        if(scan == -1) {            
            System.out.println("No more inputs, final answer was  " + all);
            break;
            }
        }
    }

if (operator == 2){

        System.out.println("Press -1 to cancel ");

    while(i <=howmany) {

        i++;
        System.out.println("Enter number" + i);
        System.out.println("So far your numbers is " + all);
        scan = scanner.nextInt();   
        all -= scan;

        if(i-1 == howmany ) {
            System.out.println("Your final answer is " + all);
        }

        if(scan == -1) {            
            System.out.println("No more inputs, final answer was  " + all);
            break;
            }
        }
    }
if (operator == 3){
all = 1;
System.out.println("Press -1 to cancel ");

while(i <=howmany) {

i++;
System.out.println("Enter number" + i);
System.out.println("So far your numbers is " + all);
scan = scanner.nextInt();   
all *= scan;

if(i-1 == howmany ) {
    System.out.println("Your final answer is " + all);
}

if(scan == -1) {            
    System.out.println("No more inputs, final answer was  " + all);
    break;
    }
}
}   
if (operator == 4){

System.out.println("Press -1 to cancel ");

while(i <=howmany) {

i++;
System.out.println("Enter number" + i);
System.out.println("So far your numbers is " + all);
scan = scanner.nextInt();
all = scan;


if(i-1 == howmany ) {
    System.out.println("Your final answer is " + all);
}

if(scan == -1) {            
    System.out.println("No more inputs, final answer was  " + all);
    break;
    }
}
}   
if (operator == 5){

System.out.println("Press -1 to cancel ");

while(i <=howmany) {

i++;
System.out.println("Enter number" + i);
System.out.println("So far your numbers is " + all);
scan = scanner.nextInt();   
all %= scan;

if(i-1 == howmany ) {
    System.out.println("Your final answer is " + all);
}

if(scan == -1) {            
    System.out.println("No more inputs, final answer was  " + all);
    break;
    }
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: @GBlodgett Right now i just have it prefixed to whatever number they pick 1-5 itll just keep the same operation going versus changing it. So i want something like  5*5+100 /3 all user inputted  through scanner

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know where to start when coding, it can help to write the algorithm in sentences first, and then convert into code. For a calculator program for example, I would start with this basic structure:

```
// need a data structure to hold all numbers
// need a data structure to hold all operations

while(the user wishes to continue) {
    while(the user has not hit =) {
        // use the scanner to get the next number (if it's -1, exit program)
        // use the scanner to get the next operator (if it's = then exit inner 
        // loop to report result)
    }
    // need variable to hold calculation result, instantiate to first number
    for(loop through numbers data structure) {
        // apply next operator to the running result and next number
    }
    // report result to user
}
```

Something else to consider: a calculator should be able to use -1 in calculations. I'm not sure if this is a requirement of what you're working on, so I left it as you described, but what would be more in line with the spirit of a calculator would be to do something like ask the user after each successful calculation if they'd like to continue (y/n).